# How to extract everything until first occurrence of pattern

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to use the [stringr](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr) package in R to extract everything from a string up until the first occurrence of an underscore.

**What I've tried**

```
str_extract("L0_123_abc", ".+?(?<=_)")
> "L0_"
```

Close but no cigar.  How do I get this one?  Also, Ideally I'd like something that's easy to extend so that I can get the information in between the 1st and 2nd underscore and get the information after the 2nd underscore.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

To get `L0`, you may use

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract("L0_123_abc", "[^_]+")
[1] "L0"
```

The `[^_]+` matches 1 or more chars other than `_`.

Also, you may split the string with `_`:

```
x <- str_split("L0_123_abc", fixed("_"))
> x
[[1]]
[1] "L0"  "123" "abc"
```

This way, you will have all the substrings you need.

The same can be achieved with

```
> str_extract_all("L0_123_abc", "[^_]+")
[[1]]
[1] "L0"  "123" "abc"
```

Answer (score 15):

The regex lookaround should be

```
str_extract("L0_123_abc", ".+?(?=_)")
#[1] "L0"
```

Comment: What does the first `?` do in this pattern?

Comment: it is needed as without it I get `"L0_123"`

Comment: @its.me.adam Sorry, didnt test it before commenting.   It is a greedy match.  You can check [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

Comment: So the `?` has the pattern match both `any character` and `any character at least once`. But I don't understand how this prevents  matching`"L0_123"`.

Answer (score 10):

Using gsub...

```
gsub("(.+?)(\\_.*)", "\\1", "L0_123_abc")
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `sub` from *base* using `_.*` taking everything starting from `_`.

```
sub("_.*", "", "L0_123_abc")
#[1] "L0"
```

Or using `[^_]` what is everything but not `_`.

```
sub("([^_]*).*", "\\1", "L0_123_abc")
#[1] "L0"
```

or using `substr` with `regexpr`.

```
substr("L0_123_abc", 1, regexpr("_", "L0_123_abc")-1)
#substr("L0_123_abc", 1, regexpr("_", "L0_123_abc", fixed=TRUE)-1) #More performant alternative
#[1] "L0"
```