# extracting data before a sign in R

Tags: r, regex

I need to extract all the text before a sign, in this case a dash.
I have data like these:

```
  text1 <- "Médicos-Otros"
  text2 <- "Disturbio-Escándalo"
  text3 <- "Accidente-Choque"
```

The problem is that the words that i am trying to extract don't have the same lenght so i can't try some of these

```
extract <- substring(text1, 1, n)
```

desired results are:

```
extract1 <- "Médicos"
extract2 <- "Disturbio"
extract3 <- "Accidente"
```

Comment: [Remove part of string after “.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617702/remove-part-of-string-after), [Get the strings before the comma with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320966/get-the-strings-before-the-comma-with-r), [Extract part of string (till the first semicolon) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752250/extract-part-of-string-till-the-first-semicolon-in-r), [How to extract everything until first occurrence of pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113963/how-to-extract-everything-until-first-occurrence-of-pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sub` does the job:

```
sub("(.*)-.*", "\\1", c(text1, text2, text3))
# [1] "Médicos"   "Disturbio" "Accidente"
```

Here we split each character into: what goes before the dash (`(.*)`), the dash itself, and what goes after the dash (`.*`). Each character then is replaced by the first part (`\\1`).

Analogously you may extract the second half:

```
sub(".*-(.*)", "\\1", c(text1, text2, text3))
# [1] "Otros"     "Escándalo" "Choque"
```

Comment: Thank you. One more thing, just in order to understand how this work: if there were a lot of dashes and i need one in particular ¿How can i get the desired part of text?

Comment: @ArmandoGonzálezDíaz, to extract, say, the 5th part (after the 4th dash), use `sub("(.*?-){4}(.*?)($|-.*)", "\\2", txt)`, and so on (need to change only `{4}` to something else). The pattern now is quite different because the total number of dashes is unknown. If you knew that there are four dashes in total, the fifth part would be `sub(".*-.*-.*-.*-(.*)", "\\1", txt)
`, if we keep going in the same fashion, but clearly there are more concise ways once the situation gets more complex. For the future keep in mind to make sure that your initial question includes everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions:

```
text1 <-  "Médicos-Otros"
text2 <-  "Disturbio-Escándalo"
text3 <-  "Accidente-Choque"

extract1 <- gsub("\\-.*", "", text1)
extract2 <- gsub("\\-.*", "", text2)
extract3 <- gsub("\\-.*", "", text3)
```

This translates to match everything (and including) after dash ("-") and replace with nothing "".

Comment: Thank you. Now i need to extract the second part of text ¿How i can do it?

Comment: @ArmandoGonzálezDíaz: If you're interested in both parts of each string, but having them separate, you're better off with Jilbers `strsplit()` approach. Eg: `do.call(rbind, strsplit(c(text1, text2, text3), "-"))`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `strsplit`

```
> sapply(strsplit(c(text1, text2, text3), "-"), "[[", 1)
[1] "Médicos"   "Disturbio" "Accidente"
```

Consider `str_extract` from stringr package as another alternative

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract(c(text1, text2, text3), "\\w+")
[1] "Médicos"   "Disturbio" "Accidente"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex with positive look-ahead

```
sapply(c(text1, text2, text3), 
  function(x)
    regmatches(x, regexpr(".*(?=-)", x, perl=TRUE))
)
#      Médicos-Otros Disturbio-Escándalo    Accidente-Choque 
#          "Médicos"         "Disturbio"         "Accidente"
```